# Extending to Continuous Function？

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have two functions

$f(x, y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \qquad (x, y) \neq 0$ and

$f(x, y) = \dfrac{\sin(xy)}{x} \qquad x \neq 0$

which of the two functions can be extended to a continuous function defined on all of $R^2$ and why if or if not possible?

Comment: Well I know there is a Tietze extension theorem, but I'm not sure it can apply in this case.

Comment: No you can't, to use Tietze extension theorem your function needs to be defined on closed set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can extend these functions to the whole real plane, there is only one way to do it, and it is by assigning the function value at the points it is missing the limit of $f$ when $(x,y)$ goes to those missing points where it is not defined yet. All you have to do is see if the limits exist and if they do, compute them to find the values of $f$ you must put there.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $\dfrac{x\cdot x}{x^2+x^2}=\dfrac12$, $\dfrac{x\cdot 2x}{x^2+(2x)^2}=\dfrac25$ and $\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{x} = \dfrac{y\sin(xy)}{xy}$.

Comment: If we set $y=k x$, then $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{kx^2}{x^2+k^2x^2}=\frac{k x^2}{(1+k^2)x^2}=\frac{k}{1+k^2}, x\neq 0$, so $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ does not exist.